# HISTTIMEFORMAT config ignored and defaulting to epoch

Tags: bash

I tried setting up my bash config to save all my bash history and show a timestamp. I was wondering what am I doing wrong, because I cannot get my timestamp to be shown in ISO8601 format, it always shows as epoch regardless of how I change it.

This is my current config:

```
export HISTFILESIZE=
export HISTSIZE=
export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T "
export HISTFILE=~/.bash_eternal_history
PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

Answer (score 0):

With `HISTFILESIZE=''` and `HISTSIZE=''`

There is nothing being stored in the history file:

> HISTFILESIZE :  .... If the value is 0, the history file is truncated to zero size. ...

And nothing is being kept in memory:

> HISTSIZE : ... If the the value is 0, commands are not saved in the history list. ...

There must be command lines stored for the HISTTIMEFORMAT to work.